# Re: Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I changed my account settings yesterday to IMAP instead of POP3. Now, I've lost the Quick Click capability. I am, even, unable to find the word "categories" so that I can reset it up. Has anyone else encountered this issue? How can I fix it?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The categories feature is not available via IMAP. The email server is just not configured for it. You have to use an MS Exchange server to take full advantage of that feature.